# Avoiding scaffoldings.css.scss to be generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

is there a way to customize Rails 3 generator in order not to create scaffoldings.css.scss when running

```
rails g scaffolding MyScaffold
```

?

I still want myScaffold.css.scss so adding the code below to application.rb doesn't solve my issue. `

```
config.generators do |g|      
  g.stylesheets false
end`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a --no-stylesheets flag you can use:

```
rails g scaffold MyModel --no-stylesheets
```

Comment: Your solution is equal to  
config.generators do |g|      
  g.stylesheets false
end`
and it prevents the generation of myScaffolding.css.scss as well, not what I want.

Thanks anyway